# Mysql group by select most recent record

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a reports table with organisation id's that has multiple rows for every year, example.

```
| ID | Organisation ID | Report Year 
--------------------------------------
|  1 |   1             | 2016        
|  2 |   1             | 2017        
|  3 |   12            | 2016        
|  4 |   12            | 2017        
|  5 |   13            | 2016        
|  6 |   13            | 2017        
|  7 |   14            | 2016
```

and a report_files table as follows

```
| ID | Report Type ID | Report ID   | Report File
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 1              | 1          | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
|  3 | 1              | 3          | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
|  5 | 1              | 5          | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
|  6 | 1              | 6          | org1_test_report_2017.pdf
|  7 | 1              | 7          | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
```

I'd like to get the most recent record from reports table i.e if 2016 and 2017 rows exist i'd like to get 2017 and if only 2016 exist then get that and left join that on reports_file table to get the report_file column with the file name if one exist for that id if not return null. Something like this.

```
| Report ID | Organisation ID | Report File
----------------------------------------------
| 2         | 1               | NULL
| 4         | 12              | NULL
| 6         | 13              | org1_test_report_2017.pdf
| 7         | 14              | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
```

Might not have explained properly, please let me know if the question is not clear. Basically want to group by organisation_id on the reports table but get the most recent row, if 2017 exists then get that if not get 2016 and then left join that on report_files table to see if a file is attached to the most recent report id if so return file else return null. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little SQL fiddle would help immensely for us to try this.

Comment: "I'd like to get the most recent record from reports table i.e if 2016 and 2017 rows exist i'd like to get 2017 and if only 2016" -> this sounds to me as a greatest-n-group problem in combination with a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry @stackFan not sure how to get a sql fiddle. Also can you explain what the greatest-n-group issue is and how to get around it? much appreciated guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.Report_ID, A.Organisation_ID, C.Report_File 
FROM
(SELECT Organisation_ID, MAX(Report_Year) Latest_Report_Year
FROM reports GROUP BY Organisation_ID) A 
JOIN reports B ON A.Organisation_ID=B.Organisation_ID AND A.Latest_Report_Year=B.Report_Year
JOIN report_files C ON B.ID=C.Report_ID;
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b19e1f/2).

Comment: Thank you very much @cdaiga really appreciate the effort. This seems to be working however i'll have to test this with a larger data set. I'll do that and get back to you. Cheers all by the way...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the result you want I'd like to do a `LEFT JOIN` on a intermediate table as below after selecting `MAX(Report_Year)` :

```
SELECT C.Report_ID, A.Organisation_ID, C.Report_File 
FROM
(SELECT Organisation_ID, MAX(Report_Year) Latest_Report_Year
FROM reports GROUP BY Organisation_ID) A 
JOIN reports B ON A.Organisation_ID=B.Organisation_ID AND
A.Latest_Report_Year=B.Report_Year
LEFT JOIN report_files C ON B.ID=C.Report_ID;
```

Result :

```
| Report ID | Organisation ID | Report File
----------------------------------------------
| 2         | 1               | NULL
| 4         | 12              | NULL
| 6         | 13              | org1_test_report_2017.pdf
| 7         | 14              | org1_test_report_2016.pdf
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b19e1f/9)